# Creating an ALIAS record on Route 53 using ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm trying to programmatically create a Route 53 `CNAME` record using the `ALIAS` settings with the ruby `aws-sdk` gem.

I can't find a way of doing this in the documentation. I see how to create a record itself but not how I would create an ALIAS one.

```
rrsets = AWS::Route53::HostedZone.new(hosted_zone_id).rrsets
rrset = rrsets.create('foo.example.com.', 'CNAME', :ttl => 300, :resource_records => [{:value => 'foo.example.com.s3.amazon.weast.uk'}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is an example of how you would alias to a S3 Web Site Endpoint in US-WEST-2.

```
$irb

irb> require 'aws-sdk'
irb> rrsets = AWS::Route53::HostedZone.new('Z1234').rrsets #replace Z123 with your hosted zone in which you are creating the record.
irb> rrset = rrsets.create('foo.example.com.', 'A', :alias_target => {:hosted_zone_id => 'Z3BJ6K6RIION7M', :dns_name => 's3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' , :evaluate_target_health => false }) # Z3BJ6K6RIION7M is the target hosted zone, in this case Z3BJ6K6RIION7M and can be obtained from the below link, if it's s3.
```

Endpoints & Hosted Zone Ids:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Note: Alias records can not have TTLs and require target hosted zone ids.  The reason they don't have TTLs is that they use the target's TTL.

Comment: Thanks so much for that well explained answer. One query does DNS name have to be the full url to the site or just the s3 website last part. If so where does it obtain the bucket name from.

Comment: For S3 Website endpoint, you want to use just the S3 part.  Example:s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  S3 uses the host header to determine which bucket to use.  This is why S3 has the requirement for the bucket name to match your domain name.